# Convert a StringBuffer to a byte Array in Java

Tags: java, stringbuffer

How might I, in Java, convert a StringBuffer to a byte array?

Comment: can you just do String.valueOf(stringBuffer).getBytes()?

Comment: Make sure to specify the encoding with `getBytes`... "Encodes this String into a sequence of bytes **using the platform's default charset**..." This is one of the silly areas where they didn't just pick a universal default.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I say we have an answer, from Greg:

```
String.valueOf(stringBuffer).getBytes()
```

Comment: this will first replicate the buffer. If the input stringBuffer is 1MB size then you will be creating another 1MB object and then converting it to bytes. Not a good solution.

Comment: @chendu what is your recommended suolution?

Comment: @Eric I dont have a clean solution. May be we shouldnt use string buffer. The closest dirty solution is to access the StringBuffer variable: `private transient char[] toStringCache; ` via reflections and copy it into String class variable `private final char[] value;`

Answer (score 61):

A better alternate would be `stringBuffer.toString().getBytes()`

Better because `String.valueOf(stringBuffer)` in turn calls `stringBuffer.toString()`. Directly calling `stringBuffer.toString().getBytes()` would save you one function call and an equals comparison with `null`.

Here's the `java.lang.String` implementation of `valueOf` method:

```
public static String valueOf(Object obj) {

        return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();

}
```